# Can I map with extension method Dictionary<int, ViewModel> to Dictionary<int, DTOl>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there any way to map with a static/extension method `Dictionary<int, ViewModel>` to `Dictionary<int, DTO>`?

If yes, can you share exactly how?

Answer (score 2):

There already exists an extension method `ToDictionary` that maps the current dictionary to another dictionary.

```
using System.Linq; // the extension method is in the System.Linq.Enumerable class

Dictionary<int, ViewModel> dic = ...;

dic.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => new DTOI() { Prop1 = x.Value.Prop1 /* etc other properties */ });
```

The method allows you to map both the key and the value to a new dictionary.

Maybe what you are really asking is how to map from `ViewModel` class to `DTOI` class, that is from one class to another. For this purpose you might use a mapping library such as [Automapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html).

Comment: Actually AM can map the dictionary directly.